# Different solutions for different substitutions of integral

Tags: indefinite-integrals

The task goes as following:

$∫xdx/\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Using substitution $t=1-x^2$:
$-1/2∫t^{-1/2}dt=-\sqrt t=-\sqrt{1-x^2}+C $ 

 But when using substitute $x^2$ you get: 
[image]

Why are the two solutions different? I can't find any mistakes. 

 Same for this one:
$∫dx/(b^2x^2-a^2)$ 

When pulling out $b^2$ from under the root, and then out of the integral and using substitution 
$t-x=\sqrt{x^2-(a/b)^2}$
$x=[t^2+(a/b)^2]/2t$
$dx=[t^2-(a/b)^2]/2t^2*dt$

I get $1/b*ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-(a/b)^2})+C$ as a result. But when introducing $bx=t$ as a substitute (like they did in my book) they got $1/b*ln(bx+\sqrt{b^2x^2-a^2})+C$. How did the entire argument of $ln$ get multiplied by b? 

 Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I figured you can't treat $t$ as $\sqrt{t^2}$ and simply integrate that as $arcsin$. The argument $x^2$ in $∫dx/\sqrt{1-x^2}$ must be "clean". I tried substituting $\sqrt{t}$ with $u$, but I ended up at the very beginning.

[image]

Clearly with substitute $t=x^2$ this task cannot be solved. Does anyone know what's the problem with the second one?

Comment: also u can substitute x=cosx or x=sinx for the first integral !

Comment: you went wrong writing $\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t}}= arcsin(\sqrt t)+C.$ the correct one is $\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t}}= -2\sqrt{1-t} + C$

Comment: I am not convinced that $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}}=\arcsin x$

Comment: You have: $\frac{d}{dt}\arcsin\sqrt{t}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}\sqrt{1-t}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question regarding the first integral is solved above in the "EDIT" section.
For the second integral I learned the answer today. 

 It turns out, when you single out $b$ from argument of $ln$, what you get is logarithm of a product $ln(b*...)$ which equals to $lnb+ln...+C$. Since $lnb$ is a constant, it's already been included in $C$.

 Thanks everyone for your contribution.